# Python Script convert to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, pyjamas

I wrote a Python script that easily automates something that a lot of students in my university do daily. I'd like to give it to everyone with minimal effort on their side, so I'm thinking of uploading the script into a google chrome extension that runs when the student runs the extension.

Is this possible by running my Python through pyjamas and then using the outputted javascript into a chrome extension? Or how else should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pyjamas does not work well with Google Chrome (it needs a special parameter on start or a server running 24/7).

I recommend using Rapydscript instead, the extension would work like any other Chrome extension.

You can compile Python to Javascript and include it in a Chrome extension. The site https://pythonspot.com/en/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/ has a makefile that does that.